# How to detect the place (column) where a list-view item has been clicked (android)?

Tags: android, android-listview, actionlistener

I have a list view in my android application which looks like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="50px" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listcurrent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="50px" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listoffset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="50px" >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon4" >
    </ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

which is being populated by some `ArrayAdapter`. Also in the main activity, I set a listener to detect if one of the list is being clicked:

```
 this.list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                Log.i("MainActivity", "test");

                // We know the View is a TextView so we can cast it
                TextView clickedView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listname);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item with id [" + id + "] - Position [" + position + "] - Planet [" + clickedView.getText() + "]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

where `this.list` is the list. All works fine so far, I see rows containing 4 columns; 3 text and one with an image. When I click on any position in a row I get the toast telling me which row I have just clicked. So far so good!

But how to determine the *column* where I clicked? Did I click on the first `TextView`? Did I click on the image? How to find out?

Comment: As far as i know, `ListView` doesn't tell such information. I usually subclassed it and used `onInterceptTouchEvent` to compute column value.

Comment: So again I am only able to do something seemingly very easy in the most complicated and stupid way there is? Typical android... Do you have a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how to determine the column where I clicked? Did I click on the
>   first TextView? Did I click on the image? How to find out?

if you are interested on such information, then you need to set an `View.OnClickListener` on every component you are interested in. You might want a way to retrieve the information contained in the row, when the `View.OnClickListener` callback's is invoked. If this is the case, you will have to tag the single views with the position, in your `getView`. This way you can always retrieve through the `ListView` the dataset item at that position

Comment: I have added the following code: imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.d("TESTTEST", "Image clicked");
            }
        });

Comment: Now I know when an image is clicked! But in which row has this image been clicked? It's a trashcan in every row...!!!

Comment: in your `getView` tag the trashcan view with the position. E.g. `trashCanView.setTag(position)`

Comment: Shall I use `setTag`? Is that the correct method? Or a different one of the 234783 possibilities?

Comment: `Or a different one of the 234783 possibilities`, what are you talking about ?

Comment: The number of methods in the android classes?

Comment: Yes, its `setTag` and `getTag`. I really wonder that this took me only 1 hour to do! I mean 'How to find out on which element a user clicked'... I expected a day to find out or so... Anyway, you helped me a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago i solved this problem by subclassing `ListView` to hook on touch events and store touch coordinates to use them later in `OnItemClickListener`:

```
private class MyListView extends ListView {
    public int lastDonwX;
    public int lastDownY;

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        lastDownX = ev.getX();
        lastDownY = ev.getY();
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
...
this.list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
        int clickX = ((MyListView)parentAdapter).lastDownX - view.getLeft();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0, count = vg.getChildCount(); i < count; i++){
            View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
            if (v.getLeft() <= clickX && v.getRight() > clickX){
                //This is the item clicked, do something with it
                ...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given the fact that click registered only if touch marker moved only a bit, you can use starting touch gesture position to receive touch coordinates in your `OnItemClickListener`. Though solution above is simple - it doesn't account for multiple touches - but I'm sure you understood the concept.

That is sure better then registering a lot of click listeners, and don't have any side effects, like broken standard handling code.